# AngularJS Modal (ui.bootstrap.modal) is not working

Tags: html, css, angularjs, django, twitter-bootstrap

I just wanna implement a AngularJS Modal (ui.bootstrap.modal)inside my project. Whenever I click a button in my page, a new pop-up (Large modal) need to be come out. I have used the bootstrap codes. But dont its not seems to be working. Please help me on it. Thanks in advance
my JS:

```
$scope.checkBinning = function(){
            selected_checks = $scope.checkGridOptions['selectedItems'];
                $scope.no_show = false;
                $scope.final_select=false;
                $("#checkRecommendTarget").modal('show');
                $scope.route = 'for_escalate';
                $scope.select_title = 'GROUPS';
                $scope.heading = 'Check Binning';

        };
```

and my html portion:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="checkBinning()"> Check Binning </button>
```

Comment: Provide enough code to replicate this. We have no idea what you have done. It's not hard to use the plunker demo in the docs to test your code with

Comment: That isn't `ui.bootstrap` code , that's regular `bootstrap.js` code. You don't use the 2 together and likely will run into problems by combining them. Suggest you read the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using jquery bootstrap js functionality in your code 
Try following :

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="checkBinning()">Check Binning</button>
```

and

```
    $scope.checkBinning = function () {
    selected_checks = $scope.checkGridOptions['selectedItems'];
    $scope.no_show = false;
    $scope.final_select = false;
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
        templateUrl: 'checkRecommendTarget.html',

        }
    });
    $scope.route = 'for_escalate';
    $scope.select_title = 'GROUPS';
    $scope.heading = 'Check Binning';

};
```

and add your modal template like in script

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="checkRecommendTarget.html">

    </script>
```

and dont forget to add `$modal` dependency in your controller